# Installing a vim color scheme

Tags: linux, macos, vim, colors

After some research, I've discovered that in order to properly install you need to create a `.vim` directory inside of the path represented by the `$VIMRUNTIME` variable from this StackOverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252452/where-is-vim-and-vim-help-files-located-on-os-x-theyre-not-listed-in-my-home). When I go into that directory to create said directory, I get denied permission to do so. When I try `chmod` the directory, nothing happens still. What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you're misinterpreting the post you linked to. You would create a `.vim` directory in your home directory, which is what the `~` (tilde) means.

Then within that directory you should create a `colors` directory, and put your colorscheme files there.

At that point, a `:colorscheme` command should find the file automatically.

Comment: @Heptile So, on OSX for example, my home directory would be my user directory, correct?

Comment: @T145 Yes, I would assume so. If there is any doubt do `:echo $HOME` inside vim.

Comment: @Helptile I've made the directory ($HOME/.vim/colors), put my theme.vim inside said folder, and nothing happens, even when after running the `:colorscheme`. My terminal does support 256 colors, so I know that's not the issue.

Comment: What does `:verbose set runtimepath?` (with the question mark as part of the command) show? If `~/.vim` isn't in there, put this in your vimrc: `:set runtimepath^=~/.vim`

Comment: @T145 Also, what did you name your colorscheme file, and what command are you running to load it?

Comment: Instead of change the runtimepath, check the output of `:version` for `user vimrc file` (the .vim folder shold be on the same path). After restarting vim you could check which plugins were loaded with `:scriptnames`. You should also check the vim documentation, which is amazingly well written. For this subject, check `:help add-global-plugin`, and `:help initialization`.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: use $HOME/.vim to store your vim related files.

Long version: read http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_05.html

Answer (score 0):

You would typically only put the syntax files under `$VIMRUNTIME` if you are an administrator and want them available to all users.

For your own use, put it/them under `.vim/colors` from your home directory.

Comment: Colorschemes don't go in the `syntax` directory, they go in the `colors` directory.

Comment: Argh! Of course. Corrected. Thanks @Heptite.